# Windows SMB共有フォルダへIPアドレス指定でアクセスできない

Tags: c#, windows

タスクスケジューラを使用して、C#のバッチ処理でWindows Server 2016の共有フォルダへ
Windows Server 2012からアクセスする際、IPアドレス指定だと認証に失敗し、ホスト名指定だと認証に成功する現象が発生しています。
タスクは、タスク起動ユーザのログイン状態にかかわらず実行する設定にしています。
IPアドレス指定、\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\共有フォルダパス
ホスト名指定、\\serverName\共有フォルダパス

なお、認証情報は、プログラムでしないで済むようにwindows 資格情報に設定しております。
Windows資格情報の内容は以下となります。

1. インターネットまたはネットワークのアドレス：IPアドレス または serverName（共有フォルダのパス指定により変更してます）
2. ユーザ名：共有フォルダにアクセス権限のあるユーザID
3. パスワード：上記ユーザ名のパスワード

kerberos認証の場合、IPアドレス指定だと認証に失敗する記事も参照しましたが、何かすっきりしません。

参考にしたページ:

- [ローカルシステムアカウントでサーバーの共有フォルダのファイルを参照したい。](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/5a04ab56-3a30-4bdb-8070-4afd3a190870/12525125401245912523124711247312486125121245012459124541253112?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissuesja)
- [IP アドレスを使用して SMB 共有に接続すると、Kerberos が使用できません。](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/322979/kerberos-is-not-used-when-you-connect-to-smb-shares-by-using-ip-addres)

原因が分かる方がおりましたらアドバイス頂きたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 共有フォルダの指定は`\\ServerName\Share`の様に、先頭は``\\``で円マーク(バックスラッシュ)  **2つ** なはずですが、実際に試しているのは質問文に書かれた通り`\ServerName\Share`で`\`1つだけで試していますか？出ているエラーも本当に認証エラーでしょうか。

Comment: 失礼しました。バックスラッシュ2つに修正しました。エラーは認証に失敗した旨のメッセージが表示されます。

Comment: 秘密情報は伏せた上で、保存してある資格情報のスクリーンショットがあれば解決に近づくかもしれません。

Comment: 資格情報を説明に補足いたします。

Comment: ユーザ名にドメインは指定してますか？

Answer (score 1):

IPの場合は認証ドメインが不明となっているのではないでしょうか？
WireSharkなどでパケットを確認してみてはどうでしょうか。
具体的な回答ではなく申し訳ありません。

(追記)
同様の環境が作成できず、推測で申し訳ありませんが
IPの場合は利用したい資格情報を利用できていない可能性もございます。
資格情報マネージャーの接続先をHOST名ではなくIPで作成してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。資格情報マネージャーの接続先をIPアドレスにすると、認証に失敗します。これは、質問で述べた通りです。